# Export JSON Mock in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to export a re-usable JSON Mock in Angular2 (for my tests etc)

e.g.

```
export class Mock {

   "bla1":1 // real values, not types
   "bla2":2
}
```

Then I want to import this in my test, e.g.:

```
import { Mock } from './mock'
```

and use it, e.g.:

```
myData = Mock
```

How to achieve, which decorators do I need, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are no signs that is should be a class. It is a POJO constant. [`OpaqueToken` is supposed to be used](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#opaquetoken) for constants.

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const jsonObj = { ... };

export const JSON = new OpaqueToken('json constant');

export const JSON_PROVIDER = { provide: JSON, useValue: jsonObj };
```

Then it can be added to current `providers` and injected into DI-enabled function

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { JSON, JSON_PROVIDER } from '.../json';
...
providers: [JSON_PROVIDER]
...
constructor(@Inject(JSON) json) {}
```

And mocked with

```
providers: [{ provide: JSON, useValue: mockedJsonObjMock }]
```

If the constant isn't supposed to be mocked and get benefits from DI, just import/export `json` object and look no further than that.

Answer (score -2):

Create a mock file like this -

```
people_mock.json
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Brad"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Jules"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Jeff"}
]
```

And in your spec file use

```
import {PEOPLE_MOCK} from './people_mock'
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkrOJ0Cqes30m3FDuO13?p=preview) here